# Why is not working my nested submenu in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, single-page-application

When i click on sub menu item **javascript** it is not showing component **JavaScript.vue**

```js
[
{
  path: "/",
  name: "home",
  component: Home
},
{
  path: "/guide",
  name: "guide",
  component: () => import("./components/Guide.vue"),
  children: [
    {
      path: "/guide/javascript",
      name: "javascript",
      component: () => import("./components/JavaScript.vue")
    }
  ]
},
{
  path: "/service",
  name: "service",
  component: () => import("./components/Service.vue")
},
{ path: "*", component: () => import("./components/404.vue") }
]
```

I have example of my code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-trailing-slash-bug-forked-yltfy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javascript` route is a child route, which requires a `<router-view>` in the parent component (`Guide.vue`).

Add a `<router-view>` to fix the issue:

```html
<!-- Guide.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Guide</h1>
    <Top />

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/missing-child-route-rendering-8rykf?file=/src/components/Guide.vue:65-85)